# HTML5 SSE get updated records from database

Tags: html

It's my first question so I'll apologize in advance if it's not properly constructed.

I have to get updated records from the database and display to the user. My first thought was to use AJAX, but after a lot of research (on SO included) I decided to use HTML5 SSE (Eventsource).

I checked a lot of tutorials and tips and got a working code, so my question to you is:

Is this the best way to do it? Am I doing anything wrong? I'm open to suggestions.

Here's the code:

Javascript from HTML/View File (using codeigniter btw):

`var source = new EventSource('site/update');`

```
var lastId = '';

source.onmessage = function (event) {
    if(event.data != lastId){
        var json_object = eval( '(' + event.data + ')'); 
        var list = '';                                       
        $.each(json_object, function() {
            list = list + this.name + ' - ' + this.phone;
        });
        $('#client').html(list);
        lastId = event.data;
    } 
};
```

As you can see I created an IF just so it won't update unless it's a new content. Ideally the SSE would just return once it had a new content, but I tested using an alert function and it kept getting the same content over and over again, so I added the IF. PS. I have a list to display the records inside the DIV, but I couldn't post it on SO it kept giving me formatting error so I removed it from the post.

Here's the Controller code:

```
public function update() 
{
    $this->load->model('site_model');  
    $clients = $this->site_model->get_all('');  
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");  
    echo "data: " . json_encode($clients);  
}
```

The controller is pretty simple and it calls a model function that just queries all DB records matching the criteria I want. I won't post the model since it's just a query.

Well here it is. I look forward to hear your opinions.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the best way to do it? Am I doing anything wrong? I guess my biggest doubt is to have to convert JSON back in JS and also to use the lastId var to keep track of new content. Perhaps there is a better/cleaner way to do this.

Comment: If you don't have a specific technical issue you'd be better off [asking here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)